# 新しいインライン形式のスペースにおいて、チャットアプリにスレッドを指定してメッセージを送信させたい

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

GoogleのChat APIを使用してGoogle Apps Scriptにソースコードを書いています。

インライン形式のGoogleスペースにおいて、スレッドに"threadKey"や"name"を指定してCHAT BOTにメッセージを送信させたいのですが、スレッドが毎回新しく作られてしまいます。

レスポンスで確認した"name"を指定して送信しても返ってきたレスポンスではnameが指定できておらず、別の名前が表示されていました。

（以前の形式のスペースでは同じコードで現在もうまく機能しています。）

```
var endpoint = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/";

//サービスアカウントでChatに対して送信する
function sendChatMessage(text,spaceId,threadKey) {
  
  //OAuth認証情報を取得
  let service = checkOAuth();
  
  //メッセージをAPIへ渡す
  try{
    if (service.hasAccess()) {
      //Access Tokenを取得
      let accessToken = service.getAccessToken();

      //エンドポイントを構築
      let url = endpoint + spaceId + "/messages";

      //メッセージを構築
      let message = {
        "text" :text,
        "thread":{
          "threadKey":threadKey
        }
      }

      //送信オプション
      let options = {
        "method"  : "Post",
        "payload" : JSON.stringify(message), 
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' +  accessToken,
            "Content-Type" : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
          },
          "messageReplyOption":'REPLY_MESSAGE_FALLBACK_TO_NEW_THREAD'
      }
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
      return response;
    }
  }catch(e){
    console.log("error:" + e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: この原因がわからずとも、新しいインライン形式でスレッドをまとめることができている方がいらっしゃいましたら是非教えてください。